# Eigendecomposition of $A=I+BDB^H$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector

Suppose that we have $$A = I_m + BDB^H$$ where matrix $A$ is $m \times m$, matrix  $B$ is $m \times k$, $BB^H \neq I_m$ and $D$ is a $k \times k$ diagonal matrix. Can we obtain the eigendecomposition of $A$?

Comment: not without further information on the matrices $B$ and $D$

Comment: What are the typical sizes of $m$ and $k$? Is one much larger than the other?